# Create backup of bigquery cluster table

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I've a clustered partitioned table exported from GA 360. Attached is the image. I would like to create exact replica of the same. Using Web UI it's not possible. I created backup table using **bq command line tool**, still no luck.

[image: clustered partitioned table]

Also, whenever we check preview it has a day filter. It looks like this:

[image: Day filter to clustered table]

Whenever data is appended to the backup table, I don't find this filter there even though this option is set to true while creating a table.

If you can give more context about handling this kind of table it would be beneficial.

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a cluster / partitioned table. This one is a sharded non-partitioned table having one common prefix. Once you start creating multiple tables with same prefix we can see them under the same prefix. 
Ex:
ga_session_20190101
ga_session_20190102

both these tables will be grouped together.
To take backup of these tables you need to create a script to copy source to destination table with same name and execute that script using **bq command line tool** under the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Those are indeed sharded tables. As explained by @N. L they follow a time-based naming approach: [PREFIX]_YYYYMMDD. They then get grouped together. The explained procedure to backup them seems correct. Anyhow, I would recommend to use partitioned tables as it will be easier to [backup them](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#copying_partitioned_tables) and [they perform better](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_partition_shard) in general.